# Not active transaction: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have the same problem. I am using spring 4.2.2.RELEASE

I have a Java Based configuration.

```
@Configuration 
@EnableTransactionManagement 
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"com.mypackage"}) 
public class InfrastructureConfig { 

   @Autowired Environment env;     
   @Autowired private DataSource dataSource; 


   @Bean 
   public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager() { 
       JpaTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager(); 
       jpaTransactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory()); 
       return jpaTransactionManager; 
   } 

   @Bean 
   public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() { 
      LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean(); 
      em.setDataSource(dataSource); 
      em.setPersistenceUnitName("javaconfigPU"); 
      em.setPackagesToScan("com.mypackage"); 
      em.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdaper()); 
      em.setJpaPropertyMap(additionalProperties()); 
      em.afterPropertiesSet(); 
      return em.getObject(); 
   } 

   public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdaper() { 
       HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter(); 
       ...  
       return vendorAdapter; 
   } 

   private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties() { 
       Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>(); 
       ...
       return properties; 
   } 

 }
```

The service where I call the update query

```
@Service 
public class MyService { 

    @Autowired private MyRepository myRepo; 
    @Transactional 
    public void myMethod(MyEntity myEntity){ 
        myRepo.save(myEntity); 
    } 
}
```

the @transactional is from spring

I have a javax.persitence.TransactionRequiredException when I don't use the @transactional or I put it without attributes or I put it with attributes.

My code works fine in an other application and in this one, it worked fine 3 weeks ago.

Comment: I have tried also beginning the transaction programmatically by following this example http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-programmatic                                 But I got again a javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query

Comment: I have found the cause of the exception. it was because there was an other bean named transactionManager which overrided the first  transactionManager created in InfrasctuctureConfig class.